# Find the differential equation of all circles of radius 1 and centers on $y=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

Find the differential equation of all circles of radius 1 and centers on $y=x$, I've answered several problems with circles finding its equation but not like $y=x$ can someone please explain this to me step by step? By the way my textbook says the answer is $(y-x)^2[1+(y')^2=(1+y')^2$

Answer (score 4):

then circles are given by $$(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2 = 1, a \text{ arbitrary}. \tag 1 $$
differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $x,$ we have $$(x-a) +(y-a)y' = 0\tag 2 $$ solving $(2)$  for $a,$  we get $$a = \frac{x+yy'}{1+y'}, \quad x - a=\frac{(x-y)y'}{1+y'}, \quad y - a =\frac{y-x}{1+y'}\tag 3 $$

subbing $(3)$ in $(1)$  gives you $$(x-y)^2\left(y'^2+1\right) = (1+y')^2 $$

Comment: how did you get $x-a$= to that?

Comment: it follows from $a = \frac{x+yy'}{1+y'}.$